# Download a file from a FTP server to a specific location?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I know I can get to a FTP location by accessing:

```
open ftp://user:pass@my_ftp_server/my_file
```

This will download the file in the Downloads folder.

How can I tell FTP tp download the file to a specific location I want?

I am looking for something like:

```
open ftp://user:pass@my_ftp_server/my_file=/tmp/fileDownloadedFromFtp
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `curl` instead of `open` :-)

- `curl 'ftp://user:pass@my_ftp_server/my_file' > '/tmp/fileDownloadedFromFtp'`
- `curl -o '/tmp/fileDownloadedFromFtp' 'ftp://user:pass@my_ftp_server/my_file'`
- `(cd /tmp && curl -O 'ftp://user:pass@my_ftp_server/my_file')`

`curl` by default dumps the received data on standard output, so the first option just uses output redirection to store it. The second option explicitely sets the target directory/name, the third changes to the target directory first and then has `curl` store the data into a file named the same way as on the source side.

If you want to avoid that username/password are visible to other users by running `ps` (or by looking into your shell history)

- create a text file `.netrc` in your home directory with the following content (replace `my_ftp_server`, `user`, `pass` with the real values)

  ```
  machine my_ftp_server login user password pass
  ```
- run `chmod 600 ~/.netrc`
- Use `curl -n ...`

Comment: How can I do it using `open` ?

Comment: @jake Is there a specific reason you want to use `open` for this? I don‘t want to question that, but it might help to find alternative solutions if open doesn’t work.

Comment: Yes, in our mac there is no `curl`(and multiple other programs)  - we remove it for security reasons so I need to use `open`

Comment: @Jake Can you edit the question and list the programs one can *not* use because of this? There may be other ways but it will be hard to find solutions if one has to guess what's available. Also, are you allowed to install additional applications?

Comment: I don't have the full list, we're not allow to install additional applications